# Why is forEach not working for children?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, parent-child

I have a `<div>` with some child `<div>` in it. E.g.

```
<div id="niceParent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I tried to loop through them with the `forEach` function, because I thought that `document.getElementById("niceParent").children` is an array, as I can access the elements with

```
console.log(document.getElementById("niceParent").children[1]);
console.log(document.getElementById("niceParent").children[2]);
console.log(document.getElementById("niceParent").children[3]);
console.log(document.getElementById("niceParent").children[4]);
```

Hence I tried

```
document.getElementById("niceParent").children.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```

which is not working. I get

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).children.forEach is not a function
```

As a workaround I also tried it with a—much more complicated—`for..in` loop:

```
for (var i in document.getElementById("niceParent").children) {
  if (document.getElementById("niceParent").children[i].nodeType == 1) console.log(document.getElementById("niceParent").children[i]);
}
```

which worked as expected.

Why?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Because `.children` contains an [`HTMLCollection` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array. An `HTMLCollection` object is an *array-like* object, which exposes a `.length` property and has numeric properties, just *like* arrays, but it does not inherit from `Array.prototype` and thus is not an array.

You can convert it to an array using `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementById(...).children);
```

---

**ECMAScript 6** introduces a new API for converting iterators and array-like objects to real arrays: [`Array.from` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Use that if possible since it makes the intent much clearer.

```
var children = Array.from(document.getElementById(...).children);
```

Comment: I would like to accept both Felix Kling and lonesomeday answer, as they are the same despite some aliases used. Thank you. Especially for the link to MDN.

Comment: In ECMAScript6 one can use `Array.prototype.from()` to state the intent of converting to an Array in a more clear way.

Comment: While Array.from or slice are technically possible, surely the conversion process involved makes these considerably less efficient than simply traversing the original NodeList with a for loop?

Comment: Actually [.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) contains an `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`. `NodeList` does have a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method nowadays, while `HTMLCollection` does not.

Comment: You can do even better with ES6 thanks to the spread operator. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52403188/1248177) below :)

Answer (score 18):

A way to convert a `HTMLCollection` like `.children` to an array to use `forEach()` (or `map()`, etc.) is to use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in an array `[]`.

```
var children = [...document.getElementById('x').children];
```

for example:

```
[...document.getElementById('x').children].forEach(child => console.log(child))
```

This is an es6 feature. It will work on all modern browser.

```js
[...document.getElementById('niceParent').children].forEach(child => console.log(child.textContent))
```

```html
<div id="niceParent">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</div>
```

If, on visual studio code, you faced the error:

> Type 'IterableIterator' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

Instead of

```js
[...document.getElementById('niceParent').children]
```

you can rely on

```js
Array.from(document.getElementById('niceParent').children)
```

More on [`downlevelIteration`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046124/1248177)

Answer (score 12):

[`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children) is **not** an array. It is an object called an `HTMLCollection`. These do not have an array’s methods (though they do have the `length` property).

To loop through it, you'll have to convert it into an array, which you can do using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("niceParent").children);

children.forEach(…);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

And after this you can call forEach on your collection:

```
document.getElementById("niceParent").children.forEach(...)
```

The best and most secure way would be actually to only add forEach in cases when it doesn't already exist:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
   NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
if (window.HTMLCollection && !HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach) {
   HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Comment: That will, however, cause difficulties if combined with the `for..in` approach.

Comment: I recommend to read the article: ["What’s wrong with extending the DOM"](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: Nevertheless it’s interesting to know that this is possible.

Comment: Don’t do this. If you have to extend native prototypes, check for their existence _first_, then [add a _non-enumerable, non-constructible method_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491279/4642212) to the prototype. For reference, [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) exists in recent browsers.

Comment: Extending the DOM with a good polyfill is not bad practice in my opinion. I would recommend this answer. @SebastianSimon The MDN page you've linked lists this answer as a Polyfill: "The above behavior is how many browsers actually implement NodeList.prototype.forEach"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @dehart, extended the answer with a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a clean approach with a lightweight npm module to resolve above issue, please check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreach-array

Ex:

```
import each from 'foreach-array';

const array = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Country'];

each(array, (value, index, array) => {
    console.log(index + ': ' + value);
});

// Console log output will be:
//      0: First Name
//      1: Last Name
//      2: Country
```

For your scenario it is `document.getElementById("niceParent").children` instead of `array` in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can be an easy solution:

```
document.getElementById("niceParent").childNodes.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
});
```