# Not able to use forEach(func) on array'ish object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I know how to use `forEach` in general but today I hit a spot that puzzled me. I've googled it but didn't get anything that I didn't already know.

I'm starting with TypeScript because of Angular and I've accessed a set of controls from the DOM. Then, I pick one of them and get to its children.

```
@ViewChildren("marker") markers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

this.markers.forEach(item => {
  let element = item.nativeElement;

  //item.children.forEach(child => {child.classList.add("poof"); });
  for (let child of element.children)
    child.classList.add("poof");
});
```

According to the console, it looks like an array, as it's a list with brackets (although `typeof`  tells me it's an object).

I'm confused about this and curious about why the commented out code doesn't work. Not sure what to google for, neither.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15094927/908842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEach is a method of an Array. TypeScript will only allow you to call methods it understands is available for that type.

If the type QueryList<> is not an array but rather an object that has the same behavior as an array at runtime TS will not know it.

You can either use the for..of loop or if you want to stick with forEach you can make `QueryList<> extends Array<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` method belongs to the Array prototype (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), therefore it can only be used on variables which are of type Array.

The QueryList type implements the Iterable interface (as per Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html)), therefore it allows looping with `for ... of`.

What the Google Chrome (or any other browser) console prints is different from what the object actually is.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait until `markers` are rendered in the view:

```
@ViewChildren("marker") markers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.markers.forEach(item => {
     let element = item.nativeElement;

    //item.children.forEach(child => {child.classList.add("poof"); });
    for (let child of element.children)
      child.classList.add("poof");
    });
}
```