# nodeList.style.display = 'flex' is not working

Tags: javascript, flexbox, nodelist

i can't find the problem. I am just getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" this error.

```
function filterTodo(e){
const todos = todoList.childNodes;
todos.forEach(function(todo){
    switch (e.target.value){
        case "all" :
            todo.style.display = 'flex';
            break;

        case "completed" :
            if(todo.classList.contains('completed')){
                todo.style.display = 'flex';
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I think todo is not a dom element that we are expecting. Could you check todo using console.log()?

Comment: <div class="todo"><li class="todo-item">something</li> this is the output of console.log(todo)

Comment: just use `node.children` instead of `node.childNodes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childNodes` includes *all* nodes, including text nodes (which don't have a `style` property.

Use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead. That provides the child *elements*.

Comment: when i have used todoList.children then it is showing that todos.forEach is not a function :/

Comment: [Apply Array.from as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094886/why-is-foreach-not-working-for-children)

Answer (score 0):

You can use property cahining here....

```
todo?.style?.display = 'flex'
```

What it does is it will check for the property first. If it finds the exact property then assigns the value otherwise skips.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment showing this error now

Comment: then you can use this --->
if (todo.style.display) todo.style.display = 'flex';